# Saving a Counter to shared preferences after a button is clicked, but it doesn't save

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences, saving-data

I am trying to have a button increment a counter and have the counter saved to shared preferences so that even if the app is exited, the counter value doesn't reset to 0. I have tried to use shared preferences but the value just wont save. I have had a look at other similar forms but cant understand how to implement it to my version of the code.

Here is the code :

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Screen2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView showValue;

    int counter = 0;

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen2);

        showValue = findViewById(R.id.AnnieCount);
        //showValue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

      sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 
      Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        public void AnCount(View v) {
            //increase the count
            counter++;
            showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit ();
            editor.putInt("annie", Integer.valueOf(counter));
            // openDialog();

    }
```

EDIT

Here is the minimum working code & XML :

MainActivity :

```
package com.example.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView showValue;
    int counter = 0;

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showValue = findViewById(R.id.AnnieCount);
        //showValue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    }


    public void AnCount(View v) {
        //increase the count
        counter++;
        showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("counter", counter);
        editor.commit();
        // openDialog();
    }
}
```

Here is the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AnnieCount"
        android:layout_width="57dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="167dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="167dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/AnnieBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AnnieBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="72dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:onClick="AnCount"
        android:text="annie_liou"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/AnnieCount"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

All I need to happen is for the increment value to be stored even after closing the app completey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `editor.commit()` before navigating away. All changes you make in `SharedPreferences` editor are not stored in `SharedPreferences` until you call `commit()` or `apply()`. You can read more from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html).

Here is how you can fix it:

```java
public void AnCount(View v) {
        //increase the count
        counter++;
        showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit ();
        editor.putInt("annie", Integer.valueOf(counter));
        editor.commit();
        // openDialog();

}
```

To view stored value from `SharedPreferences`, you can get stored value with `sharedpreferences.getInt("counter", 0)`:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showValue = findViewById(R.id.AnnieCount);
    //showValue.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    counter = sharedpreferences.getInt("counter", 0);

    showValue.setText("" + counter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I have added the editor.commit(); but it seems the value is still not stored. Does editor.putInt("annie", Integer.valueOf(counter)); - look correct to you.

Comment: Where do you call AnCount method?

Comment: Also, where do you get latest value of sharedpreferences?

Comment: AnCount is an OnClick method assigned to a button in the same XML

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "latest value of sharedpreferences" sorry I am very new to android Programming

Comment: I mean how do you verify that the value is not stored in SharedPreferences?

Comment: Not quite sure if this is what you are looking for but the value should be saved in the text view on the same activity, what I want to achieve is to have the increment (counter++) appear in the text view and then saved there (showValue), but when I Exit the application and navigate back to the page it resets back to 0. If this isn't what you are looking for i'm sorry I am still getting my head around this.

Comment: Can you add minimum working code so I can test on my device?

Comment: I updated code and it seems like working for me. You can try it out

Comment: Thank you so much Natig ! The value is now displaying even after closing the app, the only thing that is happening now is that when the Button is pressed again after Reopening the value restarts from 0.

Comment: Check the updated code. The reason is that your counter always starts from 0.

Comment: I have tried to use your edit but what its showing me is that it saves the last value (example 17) and then when I increment to lets say 23 and exit the app and reopen the value still shows 17. -- let me know if that didn't make sense.